# how to use only mat-checkbox inside mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, frontend

I'm trying to put two `mat-checkbox` inside a `mat-form-field` but maybe that's not possible, may you help me out?

Below is the code.

```
<div *ngIf="advanced===true" class="edit-dialog-doors-update-user-location-on-advanced">                            
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="400px" >
        <mat-label>{{ 'PANEL_DOORS.UPDATE_USER_LOCATION_ON' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <input matInput >
        <div  class="options-mat-label" fxLayout="column">
            <mat-checkbox class="ml-24 mt-20">{{ 'PANEL_DOORS.ACCESS_GRANTED' | translate }}</mat-checkbox>  
            <mat-checkbox class="ml-24 mt-20">{{ 'PANEL_DOORS.DOORS_OPEN' | translate }}</mat-checkbox>                                     
        </div>                               
    </mat-form-field>                 
</div>
```

Below is the output which I am seeing.

[image]

It seems to be working because I'm putting that `<input matInput >` there, the problem with this is that it allows you to put some text there, of course, that's what that input does but it's not supposed to, if I remove the input `matInput` then it breaks and the output is like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I mean putting only mat-checkbox inside a mat-form-field

Comment: `<input type="text>` add this

Comment: you mean replace {<input matInput >} by {<input type="text>} ? that wouldn't do anything, if you mean add it then I'd have two inputs to get rid of, maybe I was not clear enought. I ment using those two mat-checkbox inside the mat-form-field without having to put the {<input matInput } for it to work